# How to make a new Kafka Consumer to read offset from latest

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using sping-kafka to read from a topic that has thousands of events and have multiple consumer groups on the same topic.

`auto.offset.reset` is set to `"earliest"` as Kafka consumer configurations

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

I want to add a new consumer group that should skip existing events from the topic.

Is there any way to override `auto.offset.reset` to `latest` at Kafka handler level without impacting other consumers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-properties

> Starting with version 2.2.4, you can specify Kafka consumer properties directly on the annotation, these will override any properties with the same name configured in the consumer factory. You cannot specify the `group.id` and `client.id` properties this way; they will be ignored; use the `groupId` and `clientIdPrefix` annotation properties for those.

> The properties are specified as individual strings with the normal Java Properties file format: `foo:bar`, `foo=bar`, or `foo bar`.

```java
@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic", groupId = "group", properties = {
    "max.poll.interval.ms:60000",
    ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG + "=100"
})
```

If you are not using annotations, you can use a `ContainerCustomizer` to set the properties on a particular container.